# Parameter to pass in wdio.conf.ts to allow third party cookies

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

In my webdriverio automation, I am trying to start a chrome session which allows all cookies (refer the attached pic).

I tried my luck with the below capabilities in wdio.conf.ts.

```
    capabilities: [{

        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 5,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: [
                'disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
                'incognito=false'
            ],
            prefs: {
                'profiles': {
                    clear_site_data_on_exit: true,
                    block_third_party_cookies: false
                }
            }
        }
```

But I don't see it working.

Is there anything that I am missing:

[image]

Comment: It's `profile` I think, not `profiles`

Comment: Hi @Ace, Thank for the reply. I am new to WebDriverIO and Typescript. First of all thank you for the reply. I have changed my chromeOptions as below. It seems to be working. If you don't mind would you let know, if I am passing it correctly.

Comment: ```
'goog:chromeOptions': {
            prefs: {
                profile: {
                    'default_content_setting_values.cookies':1,
                    'clear_site_data_on_exit': true,
                    'block_third_party_cookies': false
                },
                network: 
                    'cookie.cookieBehavior':1
```

Comment: seems okay to me, I have added it into the object notation as well, you can accept the answer if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the pref object like this - I have given `JSON` values, and you can parse them into an object inside the `prefs`

```json
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1
"profile.block_third_party_cookies": false
"network.cookie.cookieBehavior": 0
```

here is what it should look like in Typescript or JavaScript.

```js
prefs: {
  profile: {
    default_content_setting_values: { cookies: 1 }, // Allow all cookies
    block_third_party_cookies: false
  },
  network: {
    cookie: {
      cookieBehavior: 0 // Allow all cookies
    }
  }
}
```